# Error in Google Tag Manager: this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm getting the following error message in Google Tag Manager:

> Erro na linha 3, caractere 13: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: const declaration.

> Erro na linha 3, caractere 32: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: arrow function.

when adding this HTML snippet tag

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        const URLToArray = url => {
            var request = {};
            var pairs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                if (!pairs[i])
                    continue;a
                var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
                request[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
            }
            return request;
        }
        $(document).on("submit", "form", function (ev) {
            var params = URLToArray(window.location.href)
            if (params) {
                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: 'field[2]',
                    value: params['utm_source']
                }).appendTo($(this));

                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: 'field[3]',
                    value: params['utm_medium']
                }).appendTo($(this));

                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: 'field[4]',
                    value: params['utm_campaign']
                }).appendTo($(this));

        $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: 'field[5]',
                    value: params['utm_term']
                }).appendTo($(this));                   
                
                $('<input>').attr({
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: 'field[6]',
                    value: params['utm_content']
                }).appendTo($(this));
                
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 8):

This means exactly what the error message says, to wit that you cannot use ES6 features such as the const keyword or arrow functions in most of GTM (some ES6 features are supported in custom templates, which would not help you here since templates cannot manipulate the DOM to add form field etc.)

The solution should be easy enough, if you replace

```
const URLToArray = url => { 
   // function body
}
```

with

```
var URLToArray = function() {
   // function body
}
```

The arrow function expression creates a function called url that is then assigned to a variable (and it's a constant, which means the variable name cannot be reassigned).

The more traditional approach assigns an anonymous function directly to the variable (and it is possible to accidentally overwrite it afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a converter, such as https://jstool.gitlab.io/babel-es6-to-es5/