# Convert array variable into another variable with comma separated values in Google Tag Manager With Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-tag-manager, gtmetrix

I am trying to convert datalayer variable which is in array format into another variable which should have comma separated values.

I have array format like this:-

```
var data=  [
  {
    name: "productname",
    id: "1356",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "Health",
    position: "1",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "20",
    brand: "Health"
  },
  {
    name: "productname2",
    id: "5263",
    price: "0",
    category: "Hair",
    position: "2",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "",
    brand: "Hair"
  },]
```

Which is i am trying to convert into comma separated values like below.

```
Product1: "productname",
Product1Price: 0.00,
Product1id: "1356",
Product1brand: "health", 
Product1stocklevel: "20",
Product2: "productname2",
Product2price: 0,
Product2id: "5263",
Product2brand: "hair",
Product2stocklevel: "",
```

Here is what I have tried javascript function :-

```
data.map((e, i) => {
return Object.keys(e).map(p => `Product${i+1}${p=="name"?"":p}:"${e[p]}"`).join(",\n")}).join(",\n")
```

With this function i can easily able to get what i want.

But somehow whenever i tried to put this function into gtm variable ( which is custom javascript variable )

Then i am facing some issue at same variable as below :-

```
Error at line 7, character 14: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: template literal.
```

The actual code in custom javascript variable is here.

```
    function(){
data = {{Custom.orderData.items}};
 var dataByComa  = ''
 var Values = data.map(function (p, i) { return Object.keys (data[i]).map (function (k) { return Product ${p.position} ${k}: ${JSON.stringify(data[i][k])}`;});}).map(function (v) { return v.join(",\n"); }); 
var commaValues = Values.join(",\n"); 
return commaValues;
}
    


//Custom.orderData.items is datalayer variable which contains data in array format.
```

[image]

So the question is why this above function is not working in gtm and giving some error.
Your help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: The ECMAScript version that you are using does not support arrow functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in Google Tag Manager: this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66187474/error-in-google-tag-manager-this-language-feature-is-only-supported-for-ecmascr)

Comment: @hacKaTun3s i really do not understood the solution he have been given.

Comment: All his solution says that instead of using arrow functions like `map((a) => a)` which your compiler does not support, use `map(function (a) { return a })` which literally means the same, the only difference being that arrow functions have come to support only by EScript 2015+. Therefore on the first step itself, your compiler is outdated.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @hacKaTun3s. Help me with template literals also.  : \.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is solely because arrow functions can only be used with ECMAScript 15 onwards. It has no relation to `Google Tag Manager`.

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "productname",
    id: "1356",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "Health",
    position: "1",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "20",
    brand: "Health",
  },
  {
    name: "productname2",
    id: "5263",
    price: "0",
    category: "Hair",
    position: "2",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "",
    brand: "Hair",
  },
];

const commaValues = data
  .map(function (p, i) {
    return Object.keys(data[i]).map(function (k) {
      return "Product" + p.position + k + ": " + JSON.stringify(data[i][k]);
    });
  })
  .map(function (v) {
    return v.join(",\n");
  });

console.log(commaValues.join(",\n"));
```

Comment: hey thanks for this one : ) , well i am new to javascript. I tried your solution but it giving me one template literal error. Can you please help me in this also...? Error:- "Error at line 7, character 14: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: template literal" .

Comment: Please share all of your code. We can't help without seeing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have added image in question....please check

Comment: Would you please give me actual code without template literals.

Comment: Removed template literals.

Answer (score 1):

try this simple looping

```js
const data=  [
  {
    name: "productname",
    id: "1356",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "Health",
    position: "1",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "20",
    brand: "Health"
  },
  {
    name: "productname2",
    id: "5263",
    price: "0",
    category: "Hair",
    position: "2",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "",
    brand: "Hair"
  }]
  
  let dataByComa = '';

data.forEach((d, i)=> {
  Object.keys(d).forEach((key)=> {
    dataByComa += `product${i+1}_${key}=${d[key]}, \n`
  });
})
console.log(dataByComa)
```

Comment: Still giving same error :- " Error at line 3, character 26: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function" ....

Comment: changed to arrow function

Comment: @sojin The error he's getting is related to his JS engine being outdated and not supporting arrow functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you have any other idea without using arrow function? , I mean GTM using some ECMAScript version that is not support arrow function

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: Yes @hacKaTun3s right !.

Comment: just replace arrow function with normal functions