# Google Tag Manager doesnt accept a basic GTAG script

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-script

I am getting frustrated.
I want to use custom html code in GTM, for numerous reasons.
I am trying to integrate a basic Google Ads code via GTM, but it doenst accept the following :

```
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXX');
```

GTM tells me that this is not valid :

```
"Error on line 10 and caracter 9 : This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: block-scoped function declaration."
```

Which is really irritating me, because it's their own code... any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in Google Tag Manager: this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66187474/error-in-google-tag-manager-this-language-feature-is-only-supported-for-ecmascr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a [Google help page](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7582054?hl=en), it says you shouldn't use custom html code for gtag integration.

Please try this instead, turning the `gtag` function declaration into an expression:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
var gtag = function () { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXX');
```

Comment: Indeed, Google doesnt recommend custom code but I need to use it that way
And THANKS, your suggestion seems to work perfectly, thanks !